# Header how to modify title of the page "on the fly"

Tags: php, header, title

My header is called as you can imagine, on each pages.

it means that on each pages i've the same title (bad for SEO)

Is there a workaround to set pages title outside the header.php ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be best to see some example code for how your files are structured, otherwise you will get more generic answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make a variable `$page_title`. Set it before including the header and in the header have something like:

```
echo("<title>$page_title</title>");
```

Comment: Thanks that was fast ;)

$header = "title of my page";
include_once 'header.php';

header //
echo ("<title>$header</title>");

Answer (score 3):

Set a variable for the title before including the header, then output the variable within the header.

Answer (score -1):

```
include ('includes/header.php');
titleAndMeta('yourTitle');
```

This goes in your page and this goes in your header.php

```
function titleAndMeta($title)
 echo '<title>$title</title>';
```

Comment: That would echo the title tags at the time of the function call, which is after the header was included.  This wouldn't solve the original poster's problem.