# How to change title of the page after including header.php?

Tags: php, title

page.php:

```
<?php
include("header.php");
$title = "TITLE";
?>
```

header.php:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

I want my title to be set *after* including the header file. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: The best way to go would be to change your program's logic so you can define the title in time before outputting the title tag. There are workarounds but they are kludgy.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825776/header-how-to-modify-title-of-the-page-on-the-fly

Answer (score 42, accepted):

expanding on Dainis Abols answer, and your question on output handling,

consider the following:

your header.php has the title tag set to `<title>%TITLE%</title>`;
the "%" are important since hardly anyone types %TITLE% so u can use that for str_replace() later.

then, you can use [output buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) like so

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include("header.php");
    $buffer=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%","NEW TITLE",$buffer);
    echo $buffer;
?>
```

and that should do it.

**EDIT**

I believe [Guy's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009227/php-how-to-change-title-of-the-page-after-including-header-php/13009592#32508962) works better since it gives you a default if you need it, IE:

- The title is now `<title>Backup Title</title>`
- Code is now:

```html
<?php
    ob_start();
    include("header.php");
    $buffer=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $title = "page title";
    $buffer = preg_replace('/(<title>)(.*?)(<\/title>)/i', '$1' . $title . '$3', $buffer);

    echo $buffer;
?>
```

Comment: is this method seo friendly??

Comment: yes and no. if you change a title every few days search engines wont like it, but having a different title for every page is definitely seo friendly.

Answer (score 21):

**1. Simply add $title variable before require function**

```
<?php

$title = "Your title goes here";
require("header.php");

?>
```

**2. Add following code into header.php**

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 10):

What you can do is, you store the output in a variable like:

**header.php**

```
<?php
   $output = '<html><title>%TITLE%</title><body>';
?>
```

PS: You need to remove **all** echos/prints etc so that all possible output is stored in the `$output` variable.

This can be easely done, by defining `$output = '';` at the start of the file and then *find/replace* `echo` to `$output .=`.

And then replace the `%TITLE%` to what you need:

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
    $title = "TITLE";

    $output = str_replace('%TITLE%', $title, $output);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Another way is using `javascript` in your code, instead of:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Put this in there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.title = "<?=$title;?>"
</script>
```

Or jQuery, if you prefer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).attr("title", "<?=$title;?>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the first variant doesn't seem to work. and then, if i use js, page title changes, but if you watch the source code it's not what i need

Comment: well, actually, the first variant works, but it puts page title outside of the header area, because echo goes not in header.php page

Comment: You will need to remove **all** echos in header.php and write `$output .=` wherever you have `echo`. That's the idea of the script.

Comment: Oh, and JS will always change clients side view, not the actual source code.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding a little on we.mamat's answer,
you could use a **preg_replace** instead of the simple replace and remove the need for a **%title%** altogether. Something like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("header.php");
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$title = "page title";
$buffer = preg_replace('/(<title>)(.*?)(<\/title>)/i', '$1' . $title . '$3', $buffer);

echo $buffer;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can set using JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.title = "The new title goes here.";
</script>
```

Comment: nice but it has 2 drawbacks. one is not use for seo because this code not write title tag in header. second is how to add meta description and keywords?

Answer (score 3):

**Add this code on top your page**

```
<?php
    $title="This is the new page title";
?>
```

**Add this code on your Template header file (include)**

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy.
Put this code in header.php

```
        <? 
$sitename = 'Your Site Name'
$pagetitle;

if(isset($pagetitle)){
 echo "<title>$pagetitle." | ". $sitename</title>";
} 
  else {
echo "<title>$sitename</title>";
}
?>
```

Then in the page put there :

```
 <?
    $pagetitle = 'Sign up'
    include "header.php";
    ?>
```

So if you are on Index.php , The title is Your Site Name.
And for example if you are on sign up page , The title is Sign up | Your Site Name

Answer (score 1):

Every Simple just using a function , I created it .

```
   <?
function change_meta_tags($title,$description,$keywords){
        // This function made by Jamil Hammash
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    if ( ob_get_length() > 0) { ob_end_clean(); }
    $patterns = array("/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/","<meta name='description' content='(.*)'>","<meta name='keywords' content='(.*)'>");
    $replacements = array("<title>$title</title>","meta name='description' content='$description'","meta name='keywords' content='$keywords'");

    $output = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements,$output);  
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

First of all you must create function.php file and put this function inside ,then make require under the MetaTags in Header.php .
 To use this function change_meta_tags("NEW TITLE","NEW DESCRIPTION",NEW KEYWORDS); .
Don't use this function in Header.php !! just with another pages .

Comment: Just make sure you place right sequence first title, description, keywords. otherwise this function won't work, secondly use single quotation for description and keywords. and yeah very handy function indeed

Answer (score 0):

Use a **jQuery** function like this:

`$("title").html('your title');`

Comment: this is a valid solution, but a bad idea, SEO wise. The title will not be  changed if no javascript is loaded (all bots do not load page javascript)