# How to set dynamic title by using PHP or JAVA Script for batter SEO

Tags: javascript, php

I need to change the title of pages dynamically for batter SEO and its is quite difficult to set title for each page individually

Comment: type your question title into google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - how to change title of the page AFTER including header.php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009227/php-how-to-change-title-of-the-page-after-including-header-php)

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title

Answer (score 1):

In your php individual pages you can have a variable for the title and then call the header.php

```
<?php
    $title = "Home"; 
    include "includes/header.php";
?>
```

In header.php you can set the title from the individual php pages.

```
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
```