# How to change the HTML page title dynamically generated by PHP code

Tags: php

My PHP code is generating 495 HTML pages from 495 txt files and working correctly. But right now, I'm trying to change it as a way to change the value of title tag dynamically; so I'm trying to replace `%TITLE%` with `$Oneline` that is the first line of each txt pages.

I have tried many syntaxes such as `prg_replace`, `str_replace` and much more all seems unsuccessful. In fact those lines of codes change nothing on my HTML pages.

To be more clear:

1. Trying to replace `%TITLE%` with `$Oneline`.
2. `$Oneline` is the first line of the txt file.

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 495; $i++)
{$j = 1;
$SousrceFile = @fopen($SousrceFile, 'r') ;
$TargetFile = fopen($TargetFile, 'w+') ;
fwrite($TargetFile, "<title>%TITLE%</title>\n");
    while ($Oneline = @fgets($SousrceFile, 4096)) 
    {$j = $j + 1;
        if (strlen($Oneline) !==0)
        {
        $title = $Oneline;
        $newTitle = preg_replace('%TITLE%',  $title, $newTitle,1 );
        ...?>
```

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009227/php-how-to-change-title-of-the-page-after-including-header-php

Comment: @ KarthiVenture, I've tried that already, and maybe because instead of including the HEADER I'm generating it by PHP, it's not working that way.

Comment: can you `echo` your code while you get values/not ??

Comment: Yes I did echo, the result is all lines of txt files.

Comment: i think problem is to retrive data from txt file. u just test with get value and apply to title with out file concept.

Comment: It retrieving data from txt files, I think I can figure out to retrieve the only first line, but most important part of the problem is that I could not change %TITLE% even with a static pre-defined variable.

Comment: can you post balance code?

Comment: Why are you replacing the title anyway. Why not writing the tags and the title directy to the target file?

Comment: You can write a template, then use template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to  explain it, and use ob to output html pages.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at `preg_replace()`, the parameters are

```
preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

In your code you are using the variable `$title` to replace the pattern in `$newTitle` with a limit of one. I think you want to replace the text in the target file instead.

**Update:**
There are two solutions that come into my mind right now:

1. Instead of writing your text into the file directly, write it into
   a variable instead. This variable can be searched by
   `preg_replace()` and you can change your title dynamically. After
   you done that, write the variable into the targe file by e.g.
   `fputs()`.
2. Instead of replacing the title, set the title directly where it is needed, when you are writing the header section. Than there is no need for replacing.

I would recommend solution one. You know how to do that?

Comment: Yes it's generating the target file and I'm trying to have title dynamically on target file.

Comment: So you say it yourself, you have to change the line IN the target file, or better before you write the data into the target file.

Comment: As I said the PHP file is creating, generating and writing contents into the HTML files (target files that primarily are not exist), so I cannot do anything with target files. And yes, it's better to write titles into target file dynamically, that is what I'm trying to do, but failing.

Comment: I did solution 2 already as I answered to my own question below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, $newTitle is not defined prior to pre_replace.

Answer (score 0):

After I couldn't solve the problem, I moved the retreiving data loop to above of the `title` and as [Aaron suggested at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233991/change-string-inside-a-php-code?answertab=votes#tab-top) It made it quiet simple as bellow:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 495; $i++)
{$j = 1;
$SousrceFile = @fopen($SousrceFile, 'r');
$TargetFile = fopen($TargetFile, 'w+');
while ($Oneline = @fgets($SousrceFile, 4096)) 
{$j = $j + 1;
if (strlen($Oneline) !==0)
$title = $Oneline;
fwrite($TargetFile, "<title>{$title}</title>\n");
...?>
```