# Change a string inside my PHP code sample

Tags: php

I have asked a question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228296/how-to-change-the-html-page-title-dynamically-generated-by-php-code)

but it might look some confusing and I found no relative response, so I make it quiet simple.

The code is:

```
<?php
$newTitle = 'string retrieved from somewhere';
fwrite($newFile, "<title>oldTitle</title>\n");
?>
```

I want to replace `oldTitle` with `$newTitle`

I have tried this:

```
$myTitle = preg_replace('/(<title>)(.*?)(<\/title>)', $newtitle, $myTitle);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the HTML page title dynamically generated by PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228296/how-to-change-the-html-page-title-dynamically-generated-by-php-code)

Comment: I suggest you to use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), if I understand you correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fwrite($newFile, "<title>{$newTitle}</title>\n");
```